# Python handle request param(s)?

Tags: python, flask

I am using `Flask` to write some api(s) in Python.

I think that `query-param`, `form-data` and `json data` are 3 most common type of request param(s).

I have follow [this](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/processing-incoming-request-data-in-flask) and some other documents to find out the way to  handle with each type of data.

But these are 3 distinct code. I want to know is there any way to get the 3 types param(s) in 1 code. Such as in `PHP Laravel`, i can do

```
$request->get('key);      ->get param 'key'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write such a wrapper yourself

```
def get_param(request, key, default):
    value = request.args.get(key, None)
    if value is not None:
        return value
    value = request.form.get(key, None)
    if value is not None:
        return value
    return request.get_json().get(key, default)
```

One reason why it's not available in flask, or werkzeug, is that it's not obvious what the right behavior should be *e.g.* does `args` take precedence over `form`? Do all endpoints support both `application/json` and `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?